# Lightning Tabset Error

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, but it seems like the `<lightning:tabset>` throws errors inconsistently when components are cached in the browser when using the "Back" or "Forward" buttons on the browser.

The error I am seeing is the following:

Message:

```
afterRender threw an error in 'lightning:tabset' [Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null]
```

Component Descriptor:

```
markup://lightning:tabset
```

Function:

```
Object.addRegisterListener
```

Component Code:

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="selectedTabId" type="String" default="tab1" />
  <aura:attribute name="casesTotal" type="String" default="*" />
  <aura:attribute name="documentsTotal" type="String" default="*" />
  <aura:attribute name="tab1Param" type="String" default="foo" />
  <aura:attribute name="tab2Param" type="String" default="bar" />
  <lightning:tabset
    onselect="{!c.handleOnTabSelect}"
    selectedTabId="{!v.selectedTabId}"
  >
    <lightning:tab id="tab1">
      <aura:set attribute="label">
        {!format($Label.c.TabLabel1, v.tab1Param)}
      </aura:set>
      <aura:set attribute="body">
        <c:Tab1Component />
      </aura:set>
    </lightning:tab>
    <lightning:tab id="tab2">
      <aura:set attribute="label">
        {!format($Label.c.TabLabel2, v.tab2Param)}
      </aura:set>
      <aura:set attribute="body">
        <c:Tab2Component />
      </aura:set>
    </lightning:tab>
  </lightning:tabset>
</aura:component>
```

Controller Code:

```
({
 handleOnTabSelect: function(component, event, helper) {
   var selectedTab = event.getParam('id');
   component.set('v.selectedTabId', selectedTab);
 },
)}
```

It typically happens during the re-rendering of the tabset component. Diving into the `aura_prod.js` code is daunting so I am hoping one of the developers can point me at something that looks unsupported in the code shared above.